# How to include a custom button in a VisualForce page.

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

I currently have a custom button which I am using to launch a Flow by using a VF page as the source (which in tail launches an Apex Class). It works fine in a Page Layout, but I need to put it in a VF page now and I'm not sure how to do that.

This is the VF page which the button is using as a source :

```
<apex:page StandardController="Product__c" Extensions="New_ProductReview_With_Flow_Controller">
<flow:interview interview="{!myflow}" name="Product_Review" finishlocation="{!finishlocation}"> 
<apex:param name="VarProdRecID" value="{!Product__c.Id}"/>


</flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

How would I include this custom button in another VisualForce page ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Hey @Zoom_v You can do this with the help of Action global variable.

For reference:

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product.FC_Edit, Id)}"  
  id="editButton" value="Edit"/>
```

May be this works for you.

Comment: thank you very much for your input. I'm a little confused one some parts of your syntax. I don't understand what the Product.FC_Edit is doing in it. Also, how will this invoke the Flow I have named in the current button ("Product_Review"), or the Controller ? Is it somehow calling that same VF page I showed above ?